# HTTP 415 unsupported media type when uploading file via Jersey RESTful API

Tags: java, jersey, multipartform-data

I am new to Jersey framework. I am building the REST APIs in Jersey. But in API of file uploading I got response as:

> HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and write a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem you're running into.

Comment: Make sure you add Content-Type: `application/json` and Accept: `application/json`

Comment: Take  a look to your code and check whether you write all the code and configuration correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one [here is a good workin example](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/)